# Type checking with RankNTypes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to understand `RankNTypes` in Haskell and found this example:

```
check :: Eq b => (forall a. [a] -> b) -> [c] -> [d] -> Bool
check f l1 l2 = f l1 == f l2
```

(If my understanding is correct, this is equivalent to `check :: forall b c d. Eq b => (forall a. [a] -> b) -> [c] -> [d] -> Bool`.)

Ok, so far so good. Now, if the explicit `forall a` is removed, GHC produces the following errors:

```
Could not deduce (c ~ a)
from the context (Eq b)
[…]
Could not deduce (d ~ a)
from the context (Eq b)
[…]
```

When removing the nested `forall`, the type signature becomes

```
check :: forall a b c d. Eq b => ([a] -> b) -> [c] -> [d] -> Bool
```

It is easy to see why this fails type checking since `l1` and `l2` should have type `[a]` for us to pass them to `f`, but why isn't this the case when specifying `f`'s type as `(forall a. [a] ->b)`? Is the fact that `a` is only bound inside the parens the full answer? I.e. the type checker will accept

```
[c] -> b ~ (forall a. [a] -> b)
[d] -> b ~ (forall a. [a] -> b)
```

*(edit: Fixed. Thanks, Boyd!)*

since a function of type `(forall a. a -> b)` can take *any* list?

Comment: So is your question "why does it not _only_ work with `(forall a. a -> b)`", or "why is it not useful to do it with that signature"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `f = \xs -> ...` is written with the explicit Rank2 quantification `forall a. [a] -> b` you can view this as a new function

```
f = Λa -> \xs -> ...
```

where `Λ` is a special lambda that takes a *type argument* to determine which specific type `a` it will use in the body of the function. This type argument is applied each time the function is called, just like how normal lambda bindings are applied on each call. This is how GHC handles `forall` internally.

In the explicitly `forall`'d version,  `f` can be applied to different type arguments each time it is called so `a` can resolve to a different type each time, once for `c` and once for `d`.

In the version without the inner `forall`, this type application for `a` happens only once, when `check` is called. So every time `f` is called it must use the same `a`. Of course this fails since `f` is called on lists of different types.

Comment: Ah. Right. Thanks! This reminds me of *let* polymorphism, only on the level of types (where rank-1 type variables are like lambda bindings and rank-2⁺ type variables are like *let* bindings).

Answer (score 3):

> It is easy to see why this fails type checking since l1 and l2 should have type [a] for us to pass them to f, but why isn't this the case when specifying f's type as (forall a. [a] ->b)?

Because the type `(forall a. [a] -> B)` can be unified with `[C] -> B` and (separately) `[D] -> B`.  However, the type `[A] -> B` cannot be unified with either `[C] -> B` or `[D] -> B`.

> Is the fact that a is only bound inside the parens the full answer?

Basically.  You have to choose a particular type for each type variable when you are "inside" a forall scope, but outside you can use the forall multiple times and choose a different particular type each time you do.

> I.e. the type checker will accept
>
> ```
> [c] ~ (forall a. a -> b)
> [d] ~ (forall a. a -> b)
> ```
>
> since a function of type (forall a. a -> b) can take any list?

Careful.  You seem to have lost some "[]" characters there.  Also, you are not quite getting the unification correct.  The type checker will accept both:

```
[C] -> B ~ (forall a. [a] -> B)
[D] -> B ~ (forall a. [a] -> B)
```

It will not accept either:

```
[C] -> B ~ [A] -> B
[D] -> B ~ [A] -> B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite universal quantification in a contravariant field with existential quantification in covariant fields (not legally in Haskell, but in principle).

```
check' :: exists c' d'. forall b c d. Eq b
           => ([c'] -> b) -> ([d'] -> b) -> [c] -> [d] -> Bool
```

It's obvious enough that this works: for `c ~ C`, `d ~ D` choose `c' ~ C` and `d' ~ D` as well, then the function is simply

```
check'' :: forall b . Eq b => ([C] -> b) -> ([D] -> b) -> [C] -> [D] -> Bool
```

Not sure if this answers you question, but it is one way to look at rank-2 types.